# Mining with a Zero Balance

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a geth client for a private blockchain and the miner is working now but the balances are all zero. How can this be? This is related to coinbase somehow? I assumed that a miner would automatically credit the balances. Here are the responses -

```
> eth.mining
true
> eth.blockNumber
1840871
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
0
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
0
> personal.listAccounts
["0x5842d6acb3dca819471bde56255f27670aa9b9c6", 
"0x2194d61ed691d05412c65acb46493e513ae6c566"]
>
```

Comment: what consensus algorithm is your chain using? if PoA/clique, are you mining empty blocks or are transactions being captured?

Comment: PoW - Proof of Work

Comment: Just to be clear, you are still running one miner right?

Comment: Yes. This is an odd error. It now mined a lot of blocks but nothing was credited. Also the miner seems very unstable. It sometimes just stops mining and sometimes the geth client just crashes. I have 4GB of memory so that should be OK.

Comment: Could be a coinbase thing. Is eth.coinbase (in a console session) one of your two accounts?

Comment: In error log file, I see `origin '' not allowed on WS-RPC interface` error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**For Proof-of-Work**

here's a quote from the [doc - geth/wiki/mining](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining)

> In order to earn ether you must have your etherbase (or coinbase)
>   address set. This etherbase defaults to your primary account. If you
>   don't have an etherbase address, then geth --mine will not start up.

**For Proof-of-Authority**

from this source [clique PoA](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225)

> PoA doesn't have mining rewards

That's for Geth. I don't know about the Parity client PoA implementation (yes they are different)

Comment: PoA (Clique) doesn't have block rewards but sealers do receive the transaction fees for their blocks, so unless they're sealing empty blocks PoA Sealer accounts should be receiving something!

Comment: and they do ! I have tested it on my local Clique network where my two coinbase accounts (you need a least 2 mining nodes for sealing) are not funded in the genesis file (`alloc` field empty). Indeed as long as I am mining (sealing) empty blocks my coinbase is zero. And you're right, as soon as I start creating transactions (from a third account with funds). I do receive the transaction fees.

Are you sure your nodes are synced and your network working ? Mining does not necessarily mean that transactions are going through